# Saving mp3 files from 4shared dosn't work

Tags: java, mp3, download

I am trying to download several mp3 files using a script in java. The purpose of the script is to obtain direct mp3 links via 4shared. I get the direct links fine. The problem is, I am an unable to download the mp3 file programatically.. An example link would be:

http://4shared.com/img/8dSuOD2s/dlink__2Fdownload_2F8dSuOD2s/preview.mp3

If i try to save this programatically, the link gets redirected to a 4shared html page and I get a small (100kb) html page downloaded.
However if I create a html link to this file (i.e. an anchor tag with a href) and right click-> save target as, it will save the mp3 fine...

Can anyone give me some insight to whats going on here?

---

Edit: After monitoring the traffic from the website as @Perception recommended (using firefox's web-developer's console) I get this response.. which I do not understand

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQkNZ.png

---

Anyone?...

Comment: I'm sure there would be atleast one redirect before the client (browser, in your case) is given the actual link to download the mp3.

Comment: If there is a redirect before the mp3, then why would saving the target save the mp3, but accessing it through the browser get to an html page? Wouldn't it have to the be the other way around (the mp3 file having a redirect) for that to happen?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the traffic between your browser and 4shared when the file is downloaded successfully. I'm sure the interaction is more than a simple GET request.

Comment: @Perception I'm not sure how I would do that. Is there specific software for that? Thanks

Comment: One of the simpler ways: use Chrome, open up developer tools (View->Developer->Developer Tools). A new pane will open up on the bottom part of the page. In the location bar, type in the URL for one of those MP3 files and hit enter. The requests issued to 4share will be shown in the bottom pane.

Comment: Hmm.. i think HTTP1.1/303 is redirecting it to some javascript which is displaying the HTML.. Weird :-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some times ago WebDAV really worked on 4shared. But near month ago access by direct links began return "error 500" and no more way to download files from WebDAV. Our application has plugin for 4shared and it doesn't work any more. I found a few other posts in Internet with the same problem.
I asked this question on 4shared forum, but it was removed. I think the reason is 4shared doesn't allow "direct links" for free accounts and WebDAV link really is just http-link, so no way to allow WebDAV links and deny "direct links". Also 4shared, of course can't say "No more WebDAV support" - because it is shame to remove useful features. That is why no any info in official site, that is why my post was removed and that is why you still have no any good answers for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP API provided by 4shared to download mp3 file http://help.4shared.com/index.php/SOAP_API